# Lastpage and \enddocumenthook: extra page created

Tags: miktex, hooks, lastpage

Here is a MWE that on my Mac (MacTeX, several months old) produces the expected one page of output (as also happen on earlier versions of MikTeX), but on the latest version of MikTeX (21.1) produces two pages of output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\makeatletter
\let\@oldenddochook\@enddocumenthook
\def\@enddocumenthook{%
END
\@oldenddochook}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
START

\end{document}
```

If I comment out `\usepackage{lastpage}`, then I get one page of output on both systems.

The version of `lastpage` on MikTeX dates from 2015, so it's not a change to `lastpage` that's causing the trouble. Is this a bug in the new version of MikTeX, or perhaps a fix of something that should never have worked? In any case, can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: The very lastest latex version include new document hooks build directly into the kernel, so I would not rely on code like this anymore, especially when you're messing with internal macros.

Comment: do not redefine \@endocumenthook, but use the official hooks described in lthooks.pdf.

Comment: Ok, interesting, thanks. Trouble is, if I update this code, then presumably this will mean that anyone using it will need to update their TeX distribution: this is all built into a class file, used by quite a lot of people... :(

Comment: you can add a test for the format date. `\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2020-10-01}{true}{false}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with hooks has always been deprecated.

The idea in the code is to add “END” before `\@enddocumenthook` is processed, but the management of such hooks has changed.

Thus you get that the code for `lastpage` is executed *before* your addition and this obviously produces something that is typeset on a new page (after the final `\clearpage`).

The `lastpage` package should be updated to use `\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}` instead of `\AtEndDocument`, so code added via `\AtEndDocument` would be executed before it.

In the meantime, you can use `zref`, that's always been more robust than `lastpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,lastpage]{zref}

\AtEndDocument{END}

\begin{document}

\zpageref{LastPage}

START

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely, thanks, and this fix isn't version dependent either!